# MyISAM vs InnoDB для доски объявлений

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, innodb, myisam

Какой движок выбрать MyISAM vs InnoDB для доски объявлений?
Сайт только запущен, но примерно можно сказать, добавление - около 100-200 записей в день, удаление - около 100-200 записей в день, просмотр - 2000-3000 записей в день. Возможен рост в будущем. Что лучше выбрать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: если вам волнует правильность выбора хранилища, то в первую очередь надо отказаться от mysql

Comment: @Etki аргументируйте плиз.

Comment: @Kromster я не очень понимаю, что тут нужно аргументировать. Нормальной репликации нет, hot-swap нет, есть куча историй с внезапными остановками, даже только в SQL-пространстве есть куда более хорошо зарекомендовавшие себя решения.

Comment: @Etki спасибо, такая анти-рекомендация гораздо лучше!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MyISAM транзакции не поддерживает, это почти всегда минус. Если вы завяжетесь на MyISAM, а потом начнете делать ручную механику транзакций (не советую), вы привнесете дополнительный - и наверняка полный ошибок уровень сложности - в код.

Поэтому InnoDB. И не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией, вас больше будет беспокоить производительность ваших запросов, а не движок.

Совет про buffer_pool_size вам, конечно, стоит принять во внимание, но опять же, учтите, что это - еще одна преждевременная оптимизация. Сначала научитесь пользоваться индексами, а **потом уже** увеличивайте buffer_pool_size, иначе первое время вам будет просто казаться, что у вас быстрая база данных :-)

Тем более, для таких маленьких нагрузок - чисто по производительности - разница абсолютно незаметна.

P.S. Касательно советов про postgres:  для таких задач как доска объявлений - точно без разницы. Войны между postgres/mysql по поводу производительности ведутся, но  - для вашей задачи  - нужно на пару порядков вырасти по нагрузкам, чтобы заметить в каком случае лучше mysql, а в каком - postgres.

Основные различия между mysql/postgres начинаются на хайлоаде с повышенными требованиями к специфической функциональности, репликациями и т.д.

Если вы правильно организуете работу с бд с помощью микросервисов/инкапсуляции в коде, миграция с одной бд на другую (или использование многих бд одновременно) не будет представлять для вас никакой проблемы.

Если вам не лень учить postgres - пожалуйста. 
Если у вас большие бабки, и вы можете резко найти спецов со знанием той или иной БД, выбирайте ту БД под которую вы можете быстро найти подходящих вам по соотношению цена/качество специалистов, или ту, что посоветует системный архитектор (а он у вас должен быть, если у вас большие бабки)

Если вы просто делаете доску объявлений - как ваш маленький стартапик/pet project - берите mysql, порог вхождения чуть-чуть ниже чем в postgres.

В любом случае, максимально инкапусулируйте программный код от вызовов бд.

Answer (score 1):

Ориентируйтесь на InnoDB, дело в том, что MyISAM блокируются на уровне таблицы, в отличие от InnoDB в которой блокировка на уровне строк. MyISAM очень быстрая, когда у вас маленькая таблица, за счет того, что вы не тратите накладных расходов на транзакции, но по мере роста таблицы, и по мере того, как у вас будет много одновременных вставок MyISAM будет проигрывать.

Только настройте размер `innodb_buffer_pool_size` таким образом, чтобы ваша база данных помещалась туда полностью. По умолчанию размер этого буффера 128Мб, если вы превышаете его, то база кладется на диск и скорость выполнения запросов резко падает.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто: если вам ваши данные всё равно не нужны, то используйте `blackhole`. Он хотя бы и не обещает что сможет прочитать записанные данные, в отличии от всяких `myisam`. Ну или `memory` возьмите.

Если вам важно ваши данные сохранять - вам *требуется* транзакционное хранилище. Я говорю не о банальных `begin` и `commit`, а о десятилетиях изысканий, граблей и набитых шишек как академических, так и практических в вопросах "как бы нам не потерять данные" и как после аварии стартовать в согласованном виде, а не непойми как. И ещё - как бы сделать, чтобы вся эта кухня шевелилась порасторопнее.

Из проверенных транзакционных хранилищ в `mysql` есть только `innodb` и его ответвление `XtraDB`. Поэтому выбирать не из чего. В комментариях же высказана не самая плохая мысль смигрироваться на что-нибудь другое. В частности - замечательная транзакционная СУБД `PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score -1):

MyISAM лучше(быстрее) при подавляющем большинстве селектов, как у вас, InnoDb при инсертах. Недостатки описаны выше в ответах. и 50 000 селектов для MYSQL не трудная задача, поэтому выбор базы это на будущее, правильно настроенная mysql работает хорошо и при больших цифрах. Если выбирать, смотрите в сторону MariaDb, почти полная совместимость, но гораздо шустрее и стабильнее, от того же разраба что и мускул. Кроме того, phpmyadmin заточен также и под нее. То есть вы ничего не теряете.

Comment: mariadb и percona   - это drop-in replace для mysql. по поводу "того же разраба, что и мускуль" - вы слегка широко трактуете. разработчик ушел работать над mariadb.  >>` но гораздо шустрее и стабильнее`  - пруф? а по поводу оптимизации phpmyadmin для одного из клонов mysql - я даже не знаю.